# How to access elements in other places in the Document Tree in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to XAML and WPF. This is an image of the result I need: The resubmit button showing how many rows are selected.

[image]

This is the Live Visual Tree of the document layout:

[image]

The grid is in the BottomGrid [Grid] section with its own view, and the menu ribbon is in the MenuBarOptions [DocPanel] section with its own view. In the MainView.xaml the grid has this selection changed setup:

```
        <DataGrid Name="MainDataGrid"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RequestView}" SelectionChanged="MainDataGrid_OnSelectionChanged"
                  .
                  . {more stuff here}
                  .
                  GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" 
                  RowHeight="30" BorderThickness="0" Background="#99F0F0F0">
```

And the method it calls has this, and it works:

```
    public static void MainDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        .
        . {more stuff here that sets up CurrentSelectedItems}
        .
        try
        {
            DockPanel dgr = FindVisualParent<DockPanel>(selectionChangedEventArgs.OriginalSource as UIElement);
            Grid gr = FindVisualParent<Grid>(dgr as UIElement);
            DockPanel dp = FindVisualParent<DockPanel>(gr as UIElement);

            DockPanel uie1 = (DockPanel)dp.Children[1];
            StackPanel sp = (StackPanel)uie1.Children[0];
            Grid gr1 = (Grid)sp.Children[0];
            StackPanel sp1 = (StackPanel)gr1.Children[9];
            Button b = (Button)sp1.Children[0];
            StackPanel sp2 = (StackPanel)b.Content;
            TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)sp2.Children[1];
            if (CurrentSelectedItems.Count > 0)
                tb.Text = String.Format("Resubmit ({0})", CurrentSelectedItems.Count);
            else
                tb.Text = "Resubmit";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RapidEventLogger.WriteEvent(ex.Message);
        }

        ((DataGrid)(sender)).Focus();
    }
```

But that is such a brittle and ugly solution I was wondering if anyone could point me in a much better direction. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use the [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx) to recursively search through visual components to find the element you're interest in (perhaps by name). However, this is only marginally less brittle.

I would recommend embracing a messaging pattern to communicate between discrete areas of your application and MVVM / data binding to implement this functionality without resorting to imperative constructs like you provided in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at VisualTreeHelper now. I found it elsewhere in the code base. I'm also new to MVVM (two weeks) and am struggling with elegant solutions... as you can see. Where's JQuery when you need it?

Comment: Seriously, when you have your MVVM-foo down, you'll realize how much you really don't need JQuery (or indeed any direct manipulation of visual elements).